# Bring a programmatically selected Item to the visible area in a JSF selectOneListbox

Tags: jsf

I want to programmatically select an item in JSF selectOneListbox. As there are large number of items and the height is restricted, most of the items are hidden. If I move the slider up and down, I can see the selection, but not other vice. Is there any way to bring the selection to the visible area, like in a Top in VB Listbox?

Comment: what you mean by visible area?

Comment: Say there are 100 items listed in the ListBox, but its size is 5. So only 5 items are seen and to see other 95 items needs to scrolling up and down to see. If only the 1st 5 items are visible, and the selected Item is 90, I have to scroll down. But is there any way I can scroll programmatically so that the 85th to 90th items are visible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used h:selectOneMenu so that selected one is always visible.